# Using new java 8 Optional.map causing server errors on start up

Tags: java, jetty, java-8

My group just upgraded to java 8 and there is some code java.util.Optional mapping code that seems to be the culprit.

We have a lot of lines of code like this of course if we comment them out the server start up just fine.

However, I have used this Optional mapping sytax in other groups projects and never had a problem with it when you upgraded to java8.

Any ideas?  Running jetty-9.2.5.v20141112

```
// this one definitely causes the server from starting up
// if you comment it out it start up just fine
java.util.Optional<DateRange> Dates = _obj.map(FactoryObject::getEntity).map(Entity::getDates);
```

error:

```
mlWebApplicationContext   - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘MyclassService’: Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected my project.namespace.service.ServiceUtil my project.namespace.service.ServiceUtil.impl.MyclassService.serviceUtil; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 143
Exception Details:
 Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b3a 072c 3a08 b202 5c2a 2a19 0719 08b8
    0x0000010: 0262 3a09 b802 7707 bd00 0b3a 0a19 0a03
    0x0000020: 2a53 190a 0419 0753 190a 0519 0853 190a
    0x0000030: 0619 0953 bb02 6759 190a b702 6a13 026b
    0x0000040: b602 71b2 027d 59c7 0025 5712 a113 027e
    0x0000050: 05bd 0280 5903 1301 2e53 5904 1213 53b6
    0x0000060: 0284 1302 79b6 028a 59b3 027d 00c0 0279
    0x0000070: b602 90c0 0013 b0

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:542) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 108
Exception Details:
  Location:
```

Comment: From the error, it seems like spring framework is trying to do something. You might want to investigate from that angle as well.

Comment: yeah, it's very bizzare.  there is some more error items in there that say a certain class service with the same project...totally unrelated to my new class code is failing to autowire....along with some other bean errors.  It's a very odd on because like I said if I comment out _obj.map(....) line it works fine.

Comment: it's the method references you're using, not Optional itself. Probably related to an outdated bytecode-generation library you have ended up using.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think you are on to something.  Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you mean by method references?  Some of these objects are from different groups that we use.  I've updated to jetty 9.x and mvn3 and all java 8::javac and have set my bytecode locally and the server runs find on my local box.

Comment: `FactoryObject::getEntity` is a method reference and its presence in the class code causes new features specific to Java 8 to be exercised. This confuses older bytecode-manipulating code. BTW the stack trace you have posted just points to a line where the exception is rethrown, so it's not very useful for full diagnostic.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yeah, i had to snip some of the logs out.  however, like i said....i really think that might be the issue.  thanks for you input!